# Creating custom Object using external source

Tags: community, custom-object, custom-field

So basically I have been trying to work out a quicker way of creating a new object thats going to consist of around 400 fields

I know I can use fieldcreator.herokuapp but this isnt that much quicker.

I understand salesforce have implemented a new create object using spreadsheet function but the documentation for it is awful and I cant work out for the life of me how to define a field type in a spreadsheet.

This app must submit it the same way as the spreadsheet so I guess my question is:

Either can someone try and help me format an excel sheet in order for me to upload it as an object or point me in the direction of an easier method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Salesforce blog post](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2019/08/upload-spreadsheets-lightning-object-creator.html) the spreadsheet you upload should contain both column headings and data.

The object creator determines the field labels and type based on the data in the spreadsheet. You can manually set the type(s) on the mapping screen  if the wrong type is detected after you upload the spreadsheet.

Comment: Okay thankyou mate, I thought I would have been able to set the field type in the spreadsheet, seems a bit pointless for an object with a lot of picklists.